# How to have for each loop in vba skip to next iteration?

Tags: vba, foreach, if-statement

I got a file reader from excelexperts.com that lists the files within a folder (and has an option to include subfolders). I decided to tweak the code to skip "Thumbs.db" files.

I've actually got the code working with a GoTo statement as a last resort but I know this is considered bad programming and was wondering what the proper code would be.

```
Dim iRow

Sub ListFiles()
    iRow = 11
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("C7"), Range("C8"))
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders)
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        **If myFile.Name = "Thumbs.db" Then
            GoTo nextone
        Else**
            iCol = 2
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
            iCol = iCol + 1
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Name
            iCol = iCol + 1
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
            iCol = iCol + 1
            Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
            iRow = iRow + 1
        **End If**
**nextone:**
    Next
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The parts I added in are encapsulated in double stars.

In my previous attempt, I had added in the following code:

```
If myFile.Name = "Thumbs.db" Then
    Next
Else
    rest of the code here
End If
```

But I got the "Next without For" error. That's why I went with the GoTo statement that I'm hoping to replace with something better.

Comment: just remove these lines: `GoTo nextone` & `nextone:` and it will work fine... you could change your `if statement` in this way too: `If myFile.Name <> "Thumbs.db" Then` but remove `Else` line, too.

Comment: The `If myFile.Name <> "Thumbs.db" Then` makes it a lot simpler and more tidy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the logic of your If statment around to:

```
For Each myFile In mySource.Files
    If myFile.Name <> "Thumbs.db" Then
        iCol = 2
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Name
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
Next
```

If you are going to have additional logic on how you skip files in the future, you should move the detection logic to a separate method.

```
For Each myFile In mySource.Files
    If ShouldProcessFile(myFile) Then
        iCol = 2
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Name
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
Next

Function ShouldProcessFile(file)
    ShouldProcessFile = True
    If file.Name = "Thumbs.db" Then ShouldProcessFile = False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first part works flawlessly and the second part of your code helps me prepare if I need to eliminate other files from getting listed. I'd give you an upvote, but I don't have the required rep yet.